# can't import .sql file to server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I always use these methods to upload my `database` file from `loca`l to `phpmyadmin` :

1. Get the `.sql` file from localhost phpmyadmin
2. Open that in notepad and change localhost to `www.sitename.com`
3. Finally import that `.sql` file to the site's phpmyadmin

It always worked great without any problems. But this time when I want to import that `.sql` file it gives me this error :

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>   phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>
> -- version 3.4.10.1
>
> -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
>
> Host: localhost
>   -- Generation Time: Mar 30, 2015 at 12:05 PM
>
> -- Server version: 5.5.20
>
> -- PHP Version: 5.3.10
>
> MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>
> -- version 3.4.10.1
>
> http://www.phpmyadmin.net
>
> Host:' at line 1

This time it gives me this error. How I can Fix that?

Thanks

Comment: post few lines from your `.sql` file. Basically all non executable statements should be commented in the script file. It seems your file lacks them.

Comment: What is the size of `.sql` file, what version are you using to import sql dump and what was previous version of` mysql` .

Comment: @MiyaG 253 kb. What should I do?

Comment: Okay there are two things.. one is  that you want only upload sql data to mysql OR you want to identify the issue ? Here what is your purpose?

Comment: @MiyaG Import sqldata to mysql. that's all

Comment: Okay just open sql file in any text editor and remove all host lines and simply copy the data below the line `--
-- Table structure for table `_subs_details`
--` and paste the same on mysql terminal.

Comment: @MiyaG Would you please post it as answer and give me more details to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous discussion.
Just open sql file in any text editor and remove all host lines and simply copy the data below the line

```
 -- 
 -- Table structure for table 
 --
```

and paste the same on MySQL terminal and try.

Also you can use `mysqldump` command through shell or command prompt.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Do you know why is that happened? I never had this problem before but this time I got this issue.

Comment: @afroozhashemzadeh.. some times it happened with un-proper mysqldump query, also the different version of mysql server

Comment: Perhaps it was the byte order mark, which you removed by editing the file. I had the same weird error and I noticed that the syntax error was always at the third character of the file, no matter the statement. After removing the byte order mark I could import the whole file.

Comment: After 30min of removing commented line finally it worked! simply use this website to remove sql comment: https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter

Answer (score 0):

I found similar error and by looking inside file i saw

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

that mean mysql was not able to execute query completely

you can try tables export one by one or using phpmyadmin